# Duplicate records are fetched in filtered queriset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a little bit complex combination of `| &` filter like this.

```
objs = objs.annotate(num_line=Count("lns")).\
    filter(Q(lns__id__in=lnIds) | (Q(sts__id__in=oIds) 
        & (Q(lns__id__in=lnIds) | Q(num_ln__lte=0))))
```

It looks like work, but results are sometimes deplicated (has same id).

```
   id
    1
    2
    3
    3
    4
    5
```

I thought filter is assured to return unique id though ,am I wrong??

Or is it possible to omit duplicated rows??

```
class Obj(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    lns = models.ManyToManyField(Ln)
    sts = models.ManyToManyField(St)
    is = models.ManyToManyField(Is)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Comment: What exactly do you aim to count with `num_line`? The number of *matching* lines (according to the filter), or the total number of lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you filter in one-to-many or many-to-many relations, it will create a JOIN with the related table, and if multiple objects match, then this will result in yielding the same value multiple times.

You can make use of **`.distinct(..)`** ([Django-doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)) to filter the duplicate rows.

```
objs = objs.filter(
    Q(lns__id__in=lnIds) |
    (Q(sts__id__in=oIds) & (Q(lns__id__in=lnIds) | Q(num_ln__lte=0))
).distinct()
```

What is even more problematic is that if you add an annotation, then this can result in the fact that the count will count duplicates as well. You can add [**`distinct=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id8) to the `Count(..)` expression to prevent that:

```
objs = objs.annotate(
    num_line=Count('lns', distinct=True)
).filter(
    Q(lns__id__in=lnIds) |
    (Q(sts__id__in=oIds) & (Q(lns__id__in=lnIds) | Q(num_ln__lte=0))
).distinct()
```

Comment: I understood. Using distinct(). the problem solved. Django Q is quite useful and powerful.